# Binomial Expansions having a nonzero constant term.

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

[Expansion problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDy6O.png)

Hello All-
I am not sure where to begin with this problem.  I have been working with binomial expansions for a few weeks now.  However, I have never had to find nonzero terms without having the value of n.
Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Please see 
[this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236). As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum. In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*. It is **irrelevant** whether the problem is homework. What counts is whether the protocol is observed. See also the **Edit-Images** section of the article.

Comment: For a given value of $~n,~$ the binomial expansion will have each term formatted as $$\binom{n}{k} ~\left( ~x^4~\right)^k \times \left( ~\frac{1}{x^3} ~\right)^{n-k} ~: ~k \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,n\}.$$  In order to produce a **non-zero** constant term, you must have that $4k = 3(n-k).~$